# Pytest xdist and parametrized tests is performing setup per each thread?

Tags: python, pytest, xdist

I have a test file that I run with pytest

The file has parametrized tests and also a setup that I want it to run only once before any of the tests run, on that setup I do actions that can't be done in parallel (Write to text files).

That setup is like this

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def before_all_tests(request):
# Code that I want to run only once before all tests start to run
```

When I run with no -n parameter everything works OK

When I run with -n then I have issues that I understand that are because two threads are doing the setup at the same time

Is this the way xdist works ? The setup is doing per thread ? Is there any scope that ensures me that the setup is doing only once before each thread starts to run tests ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the way xdist works ? The setup is doing per thread ?

Yes. Sesion scoped fixtures are completely supported within a single process (one global fixture when xdist isn't used, otherwise one fixture per xdist worker)

Unfortunately, pytest doesn't support sharing fixtures across xdist workers. Here's the [issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/252) reported for the same.

Comment: So the workaround is do first all the actions that should be done only once before all the tests runs and then run the tests ?

I see the issue is reported on 2013 and no solution so I guess is something that will stay like that ?

Comment: Yeah that's the workaround as discussed in that. Also you can find latest discussion on this issue [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/issues/271)

Answer (score 1):

https://pytest-xdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to.html?highlight=only%20once#making-session-scoped-fixtures-execute-only-once recommends to write the shared resource to a file and put a lock on it to prevent re-executing the code.